# Inspecting :hover/:focus element styles that comes from user agent on Chrome/Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

Every browser has it's own :focus/:hover behavior but I can't see it in inspect styles.

When I inspect an input (or any focusable element), and check the `:focus` checkbox I can see `:focus` styles defined in the context of the document, as well as user agent styles defined for the input element, but I can't see user agent `:focus` styles.

Is there any way to see them on Chrome or Firefox?

https://codepen.io/carpben/pen/abYVdLV

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The user agent stylesheet is being defined for the `:focus-visible` state instead of `:focus`.

[chrome-devtools-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHP7E.png)

You can check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-visible) for more info.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work but this was found on Mozilla documentation.

```
input:focus {
  background: red; 
}
input:focus-visible {
  background: red; 
}
```